# Binding Style Name and changing the style VIA View Model

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm

How to change the style of an element VIA view model like i want to toggle the styles when i click the button.

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource IndexVMDataSource}}">
  <Button Content="Button"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Height="42"
          Margin="10,49,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="130"
          Command="{Binding OnCommandName, Mode=OneWay}" />
  <HyperlinkButton Content="HyperlinkButton"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Height="34"
                   Margin="10,10,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="216"
                   Style="{Binding QStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

**VM**

```
private string _styleA = "HyperLink-Navi-Container";
private string _styleB = "HyperLink-Navi-Container-2";

private string qStyle;
public string QStyle
{
     get
     {
           return qStyle;
     }
     set
     {
          if (qStyle != value)
          {
               qStyle = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged(Utility.GetPropertyName(() => QStyle));
          }
     }
}

private ICommand onCommandName = null;
public ICommand OnCommandName
{
     get
     {
         return onCommandName;
     }
     private set
     {
         onCommandName = value;
     }
}

public void Command()
{
     if (QStyle != _styleA)
         QStyle = _styleA;
     else if (QStyle != _styleB)
         QStyle = _styleB;            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your `QStyle` property has to be of type [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
private Style qStyle;
public Style QStyle
{
    get { return qStyle; }
    set
    {
        if (qStyle != value)
        {
             qStyle = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged(Utility.GetPropertyName(() => QStyle));
        }
    }
}
```

Or you use a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in your Style binding, which returns the appropriate `Style` for a given string (e.g. the key of a Style resource):

```
<HyperlinkButton ...
    Style="{Binding QStyle, Converter={StaticResource YourStringToStyleConverter}}" />
```

---

As you haven't shown where you define your Styles, I guess they are in your UserControl's `Resources`. You may then get them by something like this:

```
Style style = Resources["HyperLink-Navi-Container"] as Style;
```

If the resources are defined in App.xaml you may write

```
Style style = Application.Current.Resources["HyperLink-Navi-Container"] as Style;
```

Comment: `Style style = Resources["HyperLink-Navi-Container"] as Style;` it is not found.. where is resource located?

Comment: How would I possibly know that? It's your application, and when you write `private string _styleA = "HyperLink-Navi-Container"` I can only guess that it is a resource key. If it isn't, what else is it? Where are your Styles defined? Please provide more information.

Comment: And "HyperLink-Navi-Container" is a resource key? See my edit.